# Make lambda event subscriber only trigger once then remove it

Tags: c#, events, lambda

The idea is that I want to generate a closure with the current variable state of the function call, and subscribe to an event. After the event is raised, then delete the closure. That means it is only a one-shot subscriber, and it can be cancelled at any time.

Also, I want a subscriber always subscribe to the event and not get deleted, any idea how to achieve this? or is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks!

```
public class A
{
    public event Action process;

    // publisher.
    void OnEventRaise()
    {
        process?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class B
{
    // subscribe the closure and delete it once it is invoked, can unsubscribe at anytime.
    void subscribe(A a)
    {
        string name = "one shot subscriber";
        Action showName = () =>
        {
            print(name);
        }
        a.process += showName;
    }
}

public class C
{
    // this is always subscribed to the event.
    void EventCallBack()
    {
        print("always subscribed");
    }

    void subscribe(A a)
    {
        a.process += EventCallBack;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it seems can't reference the function name inside the function?

Comment: if I initialize `Action showname = null` and add `a.OnEventRaise -= showName;` it seems work. Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your current code:

- You're using `OnEventRaise` to subscribe to the event when you should be using the event itself (i.e., `process`).
- The syntax you use to initialize the Action `showName` using lambda is incorrect. You need to use `Action showName = () => { // ... };`.

Finally, to unsubscribe to the event, you can simply use `a.process -+ showName;` inside the action body but you need to initialize it first to prevent the compiler from complaining.

Try something like this for your `B` class:

```
public class B
{
    // subscribe the closure and delete it once it is invoked, can unsubscribe at anytime.
    void subscribe(A a)
    {
        string name = "one shot subscriber";
        Action showName = null;
        showName = () =>
        {
            print(name);
            a.process -= showName;
        };
        a.process += showName;
    }

    private void print(string s)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake while typing that block of code, I changed some of them but I didn't notice it all. You method works, as for the unsubscribe at anytime, I think maybe I could keep the reference in a array in the publisher class, so I can acess them and unsubscribe using the reference.

Comment: @HSJaaa _"I think maybe I could keep the reference in a array in the publisher class, so I can acess them and unsubscribe using the reference"_ I wouldn't recommend that. You should subscribe/unsubscribe using the caller.

Comment: what's the caller?